# Why my app crash on some devices and change layout while in other devices even with diffrent sizes it work perfectly

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, popup

Hi im new to android dev i started from 1 months ago
Well i created simple calculating application
I configured layout so it looks stable and in preview in some screen sizes it was as i expected

When i run the app it workks perfectly ln some devices i tried android 11 5 and 7
But in some other devices android 10,9,8,5 some buttons get bigger... and when i click a button to show an alerte dialog it crasheess
Well in other devices the alerte dialog show and the app works perfectly without any problem please help

Comment: If your app crashes, you need to look in the Logcat tab in Android Studio to find the stack trace and error message. That will tell you what the problem is and what line it happens on.

Comment: Add more context to your question like: Error message, Stacktrace, Application code and project configuration, also, information about the devices that it crashes and the ones that it don't like: brand, model, OS version. This way we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

well the problem is that you wrote your program for android 11 and that is why it is shown and performs differently in older versions of android if you wish to make it work the same on all devices then you should choose an older SDK version preferably one that is compatible with version 5; But if you do so you might not be able to use some of the new libraries or packages that you used for android 11.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the version you are applying on other devices is supported. If you are still experiencing crashing, please share the error code with us.

Comment: This is not an answer and should have been added as a comment to the original question.